# Pass/call function from child to parent in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm slowly learning React and ran into a little problem. I have created my own component (functional approach) which is represented by the grid.

Grid component has functions in it that create a new blank line. The button that should trigger the add action I had to pull higher, to the parent.

I have read a bit and would like to skip the use of refs to trigger an action from the child relative to clicking on the parent.

I wrote this code, it works as I want, but I would like to ask you to check and tell if this approach is correct or if I should do it differently.
Below I present an important fragment of the components.

```
const View = () => {
    const [add, setAdd] = useState(() => { });
        
    const callbackOnAdd = (handle) => {             
        setAdd({ onAdd: handle });
    }

    const handleButtonClick = useCallback(() => {
        add.onAdd();        
    });

    return (
        <Grid callbackOnAdd={callbackOnAdd} />
        <Button onClick={handleButtonClick} />
        
    );
}
```

```
const Grid = ({ callbackOnAdd }) => {

    ...

    useEffect(() => {
        callbackOnAdd(() => {
            addNewRow();
        });
    }, []);
    
    ...
};
```

Comment: Im not an expert myself, but I would say that your approach is fine. I always strive to have logic related to a state in the same component of which the state is located. I, too, doesn't want to use refs too much, since my experience has been just a bunch of problems with component modularity. 

A note; in your Grid component you have an useEffect, with an empty dependency array. This will lead to the component just updating once. Usually you want to have something in your dependecy array.